# Seeing if a column value is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a complex user model with a validation method

```
before_validation_on_update :geocode_places
```

This validation geocodes the "places" column in my user table each time an update occurs.

The problem is that this validation takes quite a long time. Is there any way to only call this validation when the places column is updated? Sort of like a "before_validation_on_column_update" so to speak..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a whole set of methods available for that. E.g., `self.places_changed?` should work.

Check [the docs](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html) for more.